# Can you use a singleton in a view controller in a tab bar controller just as you would anywhere?

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, singleton, uitabbarcontroller

Clarification: The view controller with singletons described below works fine by itself.  When embedded into a UITabBarController however, it doesn't work.

Original Title: NSUnknownKeyException: Probably not the nib, could it be the singletons?

---

Here's yet another one of those "NSUnknownKeyException... this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key" questions which are abundant here.  I've been through a lot of them!  Here's the full complaint:

```
NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIProxyObject 0x683dfe0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key button1.'
```

It seems these exceptions always come down to problems with the nib having left over variables that were changed elsewhere and did not get cleaned out.  So I've worked through all my nib, disconnecting, and re-connecting, checking to no avail.  I then deleted the nib and rebuilt it from zero and I have still have the same problem :-(  So I turn to the hive mind of SO once again.

Through a series of `NSLog`s and other tricks I know the problem is with GameViewController (if I get rid of it and replace it with an empty controller the app works fine).  Here is the relevant part of GameViewController:

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation GameViewController

- (id) init {
    NSLog(@" GVC initializing");      
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"GameViewController"
                           bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];
        [tbi setTitle:@"Play Game"];
    }       
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)Bundle {
    return [self init];
}

 - (void)loadView {
     [super loadView];
     NSLog(@"loadView is starting");

     // Set up display of button and label singletons

     NSMutableArray *keyArray;
     NSMutableArray *valueArray;
     keyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"answerButtons", @"clueLabels", @"keyPad", nil];
     valueArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: [AnswerButtons answerButtons], [ClueLabels clueLabels], [KeyPad keyPad], nil];

     NSMutableDictionary *externals = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:valueArray
                                                                         forKeys:keyArray];

     // Fire the button and label singletons

     [[AnswerButtons answerButtons] answerButtonsDidLoad];
     [[ClueLabels clueLabels] clueLabelsDidLoad];
     [[KeyPad keyPad] keyPadDidLoad];

     // Set up nibOptions and link to externals

     NSDictionary *nibOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:externals
                                                            forKey:UINibExternalObjects];

     [self.nibBundle loadNibNamed:self.nibName owner:self options:nibOptions];

     NSLog(@"loadView is done");
 }

@end
```

Here is the relevant part of my app delegate:

```
@implementation AppDelegate   
@synthesize window = _window;   
@synthesize tbc = _tbc;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"dFLWO starting");

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    SettingsViewController *settingsVC = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
    GameViewController *gameVC = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
//    UIViewController *temp = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; // works fine

    NSLog(@"dFLWO: both VC's inited");

    [tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:gameVC, settingsVC, nil]];
    //    [tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: temp, settingsVC, nil]]; // works fine

    NSLog(@"dFLWO: VC's set");

    [[self window] setRootViewController:tbc];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    NSLog(@"TabBarController now active");

    return YES;
}
```

Sorry.  That's long.  I've gone as far as I can with this being a nib problem.  Perhaps it is a problem with those singletons I need to launch?  There was a previous version of this project without the tab bar controller in which these singletons (and others not shown) worked just fine.

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried doing a project-wide search for the string "button1"?

Comment: One thing to try, just in case the nib is a bit messed up and not showing you everything, is to use the Open As...->Source Code option from the right-button menu and do a text search.

Comment: Yes, project-wide search and nib as source have both been done.  button1 is in there in all the right places, it seems. button1 is part of the AnswerButtons singleton.  I suspect this may be part/all of the issue. Thanks for reading that long beast!